# Get text of TextBox that Outside the UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="700px" placeholder="Enter Title" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxUploadImages" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" 
                                onuploadcomplete="AjaxUploadImages_UploadComplete"/>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want to get the text of TextBox1 on the OnUploadComplete event like this-

```
    protected void AjaxUploadImages_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
       string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/") + e.FileName;
       AjaxUploadImages.SaveAs(path);
       string content = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: just place the textbox inside the update panel

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? What is the value coming in string content??

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void AjaxUploadImages_UploadComplete(object sender,AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
       string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/") + e.FileName;
       AjaxUploadImages.SaveAs(path);
       string content = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This code is identical to the code provided by the OP. If you have a specific answer, please provide details.